# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I am trying to enter data 'tutorial@gmail.com' at **Email** field but I'm getting the error mentioned on title/subject.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    ((WebElement)driver.findElements(By.name("Email"))).sendKeys("tutorial@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 4):

`findElements` returns `java.util.List<WebElement>`, not `WebElement`. Maybe you wanted to use `findElement` (without `s`), which returns a single `WebElement`.

Answer (score 1):

use
`driver.findElement` (it will return single element)

instead of

`driver.findElements` (It will return list)

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't see your answer.