# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium-android

I am using this code and generate this error

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class HandlingScrollVertical {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        DesiredCapabilities dc= new DesiredCapabilities();

        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");

        //dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");

        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.1.1");

        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");

        dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/home/connexis/appium/AppiumMobile/src/main/java/Apps/ApiDemos.apk");

        URL url =new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        AndroidDriver<WebElement> driver= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url,dc);

        driver.findElementsByAccessibilityId("Animation").get(1).click();     
        /*WebElement info=driver.findElementsById("android:id/text1").get(1);


        int x1=info.getLocation().getX();
        int y1=info.getLocation().getY();



        int x2=x1 /2;
        int y2=y1 /2;


        TouchAction a = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver);
        a.press(info).moveTo(x1,y1).perform().release();*/
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Envorinment variable set :**

Selenium Server standalone 2.53

> ```
>     Java-Client 5.0.4
>     Emulator
> ```

**Error log:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:397)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElements(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:54)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElements(AppiumDriver.java:167)
    at io.appium.java_client.FindsByAccessibilityId.findElementsByAccessibilityId(FindsByAccessibilityId.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementsByAccessibilityId(AppiumDriver.java:203)
    at HandlingScrollVertical.main(HandlingScrollVertical.java:33)
```

Comment: Could you give us the line throwing the exception?

Comment: This may be a bug, check this page : https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/823

Comment: Could your problem be the same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299775/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-arraylist-can?rq=1) ? Basically, using a `findElements` and not `findElement`

Comment: Driver.FindElementsById("android:id/text1").get(1).click();

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Arnaud in the comments, this has been declared as a [bug](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/823) and was fixed by [this pull request on Axium](https://github.com/appium/java-client/pull/825).

Updating your appium-android-driver to a more recent version should fix it.